# "Unknown error" when unlocking AppleID account

Tags: apple-id, password, accounts

I had to change my Apple ID password because my account was locked. When I try to do this on Apple's website I get an "unknown error":

[image]

which doesn't allow me to proceed.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem only Apple can solve. You can contact Apple Support through https://getsupport.apple.com/, it may need some patience to navigate through the structure there til you get to a phone/email contact.